# About the paper Privacy-preserving in association rule mining using an improved discrete binary artificial bee colony

Tags: algorithms, computation-models, computer-networks, data-mining, binary

I don't understand two parts in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337477217_Privacy-preserving_in_association_rule_mining_using_an_improved_discrete_binary_artificial_bee_colony):

1. The min notion on page 4 line 357 (equation 10d): I understand this as to find all the $M_{10}$, $M_{11}$, $M_{01}$ first and then try to minimize the expression in the brackets of equation 10d. Is it correct? Or does it mean to find the min first and then use that to compute $M_{10}$, $M_{11}$, $M_{01}$?
2. Figure 2 (the pseudocode of employee bee mechanism) on page 5, the condition says that $rand_{(0,1)}X_i \ge 0,5$ where $X_i$ is a vector of size $d$. I don't understand why they can compare a vector with a number. I think that they made a mistake here.

Thank you so much for helping me clearing out my confusion.

Comment: Can you provide a full reference for the paper?  e.g., title, authors, and where published.  This helps others with a similar question find this page via search, and ensures the question remains understandable even if the link stops working.  Thank you.